# Render image in mdbdatatable react

Tags: reactjs

waste_items_image: Array(1)
0:
img: "3_JAH9jh8-60fe29c679c78.jpg"
_id: "616a89377bd50f0bbc0c9bfc";

This is the response data from database.I want to render this array of images in a column name images in  react mdbdatatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little late, but I hope it can help others

In my case, the image data is stored in the state in the form of an array object.

First to add a custom item image on each object

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      data.map((item) => {
        item.image = (
          <img
            src={item.image}
            alt="image"
            className="someImgClass"
          />
        )
      })
    }

  }, [data])
```

next to initialize the contents of the table

```
const dataTable = {
    columns: [
      {
        label: "Image",
        field: "image",
        sort: "asc",
        width: 200,
      },
    ],
    rows: data,
  }
```

And then for the rendering part

```
<MDBDataTable responsive striped bordered data={dataTable} />
```

[using google translate